# Get info using PHP Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php

I'm using PHP Simple HTML DOM to **scrape** the data from a site. just like to know how to get the info separately without getting all together.

using this command i can get the full page.

```
$html = file_get_html('http://mp3skull.com/mp3/gangnam_style.html');    
foreach($html->find('div#song_html') as $e)
       echo $e->innertext . '<br>';
```

What i need is to get the Title, URL, time, bites separately.

```
<div id="song_html" class="show1">
            <div class="left">
            <!-- info mp3 here -->
                320 kbps<br />4:01<br />9.2 mb          </div>
            <div id="right_song">
                <div style="font-size:15px;"><b>Psy - Gangnam style (DJ Pasha Lee & DJ Vitaco remix) - Psy - Gangnam style (DJ Pasha Lee & DJ Vitaco remix) mp3</b></div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                <div style="float:left;">
                    <div style="float:left; height:27px; font-size:13px; padding-top:2px;">
                        <div style="float:left;"><a href="http://promodj.com/source/3594542/Psy_Gangnam_style_DJ_Pasha_Lee_DJ_Vitaco_remix.mp3" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="color:green;">Download</a></div> 
                                                <div style="margin-left:8px; float:left; width:27px; text-align:center;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showPlayer_new(11683153, '77380784862db5cfb455861b62fdc62690aca7d2', 'psy', 'gangnam+style')" rel="nofollow" id="lk11683153" class="play_now">Play</a></div>                     
                                                                        <div style="margin-left:8px; float:left;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showEmbed_new(11683153, '77380784862db5cfb455861b62fdc62690aca7d2')" rel="nofollow" id="em11683153" class="embed">Embed</a></div>
                                                <div style="margin-left:8px; float:left;"><a href="http://www.ringtonematcher.com/go/?sid=WDLL&artist=psy&song=gangnam+style" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="color:red;" title="Send Psy - Gangnam Style Ringtone to your Cell">Send Ringtone</a></div> 
                        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="player11683153" style="float:left; margin-left:10px;" class="player"></div>
                </div>  
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then you forgot the rest of the required HTML tags for an HTML page, as well as the PHP tags `<?php`/`?>`. No wonder it doesn't work!

Comment: PHP opening and closing tags is there. i just didn't though anyone will look for that. and the code dose work i just need it them separately. anyways i got the answe i wanted below. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
$html = file_get_html('http://mp3skull.com/mp3/gangnam_style.html');
$list = array();
$x = 0 ;
foreach ( $html->find('div#song_html ') as $e ) {

    $song = array();
    $song['bit'] = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ',$e->find('div', 0)->plaintext);
    $song['title'] = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ',$e->find('div', 1)->plaintext);
    $song['url'] = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ',$e->find('a', 0)->href);
    $list[] = $song;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($list);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [bit] =>  320 kbps 4:01 9.2 mb 
            [title] =>  Psy - Gangnam style (DJ Pasha Lee & DJ Vitaco remix) - Psy - Gangnam style (DJ Pasha Lee & DJ Vitaco remix) mp3 Download Play Embed Send Ringtone 
            [url] => http://promodj.com/source/3594542/Psy_Gangnam_style_DJ_Pasha_Lee_DJ_Vitaco_remix.mp3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [bit] =>  320 kbps 4:01 9.2 mb 
            [title] =>  Psy - Gangnam style (DJ Pasha Lee & DJ Vitaco remix) - Psy - Gangnam style (DJ Pasha Lee & DJ Vitaco remix) mp3 Download Play Embed Send Ringtone 
            [url] => http://promodj.com/download/3608444/Psy_Gangnam_style_DJ_Pasha_lee_DJ_Vitaco_remix.mp3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [bit] =>  128 kbps 4:21 3.98 mb 
            [title] =>  Psy - Gangnam Style (Boys Electro Mash-Up) - Psy Gangnam Style Boys Electro Mash Up mp3 Download Play Embed Send Ringtone 
            [url] => http://promodj.com/download/3614746/Psy_Gangnam_Style_Boys_Electro_Mash_Up.mp3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [bit] =>  128 kbps 4:21 3.98 mb 
            [title] =>  Psy - Gangnam Style (Boys Electro Mash-Up) - Psy Gangnam Style Boys Electro Mash Up mp3 Download Play Embed Send Ringtone 
            [url] => http://promodj.com/source/3614746/Psy_Gangnam_Style_Boys_Electro_Mash_Up.mp3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [bit] =>  192 kbps 2:53 3.97 mb 
            [title] =>  Jewish style Official parody to PSY GANGNAM STYLE MISSION ARIO REMIX DEMO FUNNY mp3 Download Play Embed Send Ringtone 
            [url] => http://promodj.com/download/3623591/Jewish_style_Official_parody_to_PSY_GANGNAM_STYLE_MISSION_ARIO_REMIX_DEMO_FUNNY.mp3
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [bit] =>  192 kbps 2:53 3.97 mb 
            [title] =>  Jewish style Official parody to PSY GANGNAM STYLE MISSION ARIO REMIX DEMO FUNNY mp3 Download Play Embed Send Ringtone 
            [url] => http://promodj.com/source/3623591/Jewish_style_Official_parody_to_PSY_GANGNAM_STYLE_MISSION_ARIO_REMIX_DEMO_FUNNY.mp3
        )

 ........ so many more
```